# TouchDown, TouchUpInside, TouchUpOutside, TouchCancel What is the Sequence of the Events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, events

Amonst the Following four methods what is the sequence of the method calls...

1.. TouchDown
2.. TouchUpInside
3.. TouchUpOutside
4.. TouchCancel

I can figure out touchupinside and touchupoutside... but what about  touchdown and touchinside... also touchupoutside and touchcancel..

for touchdown and touchinside... is it depends on threads on which it runs... because i have faced some problems with this events in my app... and sometimes it happens that they are called randomly...

can anyone explain for touchdown and touchupinside...?????/

Comment: You said that you could figure out TouchUpInside and TouchUpOutside. However, in your last line, you ask for an explanation of TouchUpInside, something you apparently understand. I'm a little confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: i want to know which one out of touchdown and touchupinside will fired first????

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`TouchDown` will fire before `TouchUpInside` because touch down is the action of your finger touching down on the phone.

`TouchUpInside` will happen after because it describes the action of your finger lifting up from the down position off of the phone